# Musescore 4.0.1, A batch job issue with .mid file conversion to .wav files

Tags: batch-file, windows-11, command-line-arguments, json

#### Issue & Scope of the problem

I followed the instructions [here](https://musescore.org/en/handbook/3/command-line-options#Batch_conversion_job_JSON_format:%7E:text=line%20options.-,Batch%20conversion%20job%20JSON%20format,-%23) to preform a batch operation with `Musescore Version 4` on `Windows 11 CMD`. Used a `.json` file just like in the highlighted example (below): 
[https://musescore.org/en/handbook/3/command-line-options#EXAMPLES:~:text=development%20version%20paths.-,EXAMPLES,because%20the%20Reunion%20piece%20(a%20MuseScore%20demo)%20has%20no%20excerpts%20defined).,-MIDI%20import%20operations](https://musescore.org/en/handbook/3/command-line-options#EXAMPLES:%7E:text=development%20version%20paths.-,EXAMPLES,because%20the%20Reunion%20piece%20(a%20MuseScore%20demo)%20has%20no%20excerpts%20defined).,-MIDI%20import%20operations), 
 I used `Notepad++` to make the `.json` batch file, to have MuseScore convert a bunch of `.mid` files over to `.wav`.

###### What Works ...

Prior to this, I checked to make sure I understood the command line prompts: 
 `C:\Program Files\MuseScore 4\bin\MuseScore4.exe -v` 
 Returns a small GUI window of:
`Version 4.0.1`

###### And ...

`C:\Program Files\MuseScore 4\bin\MuseScore4.exe -h` 
Returns a large GUI window with a shorthand of what Musescore.org Handbook says:
`Usage: MuseScore4.exe[options][scorefile...]` 
So, I'm confident my usage of MuseScore's command-line syntax is correct. The frustrating bit, is there's no error messages in the command-line. So, I don't know if MuseScore is passing errors silently or a version issue or something else. Aside from reading the MuseScore docs, and searching multiple channels under the StackExchange brand for related issue, to no avail in finding a solution.

Comment: Seen a kind of similar error when I was looking through other reports on the MuseScore Github, [this](https://github.com/musescore/MuseScore/issues/15864), but didn't help or resolve my issue.

Comment: Posted my own issue on MuseScore Github. I will reshare here when it gets troubleshooted, [the link to current issue](https://github.com/musescore/MuseScore/issues/16221)

Comment: It seems like this may be a bug within the software itself. Another person has replicated the same odd issue. 
[see here](https://github.com/musescore/MuseScore/issues/16221#:~:text=I%20see%20a%20similar%20behaviour%20when%20running%20Musescore%204.0.1)

Answer (score 0):

There still working on MuseScore4 App & docs (for [command-line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mK5H.png)). Hopefully, [this bug](https://github.com/musescore/MuseScore/issues/16221#:%7E:text=aldo%20works%20perfect.-,I%20conclude%20that%20the%20problem%20is%20related%20to%20running%20.json%20files%20from%20cmdline%20in%204.0.1.,-Write) bug will get fixed soon for Windows users trying to parse batch jobs with json in Windows CLI.